# Get substring from SQL query in C#

Tags: c#, sql, substring

I need to get a substring from a query that has a certain word inside it (the word is @param followed by a number), for example:

```
SELECT *
FROM table t
WHERE t.column1 = @param1
AND t.column2 = @param2
```

What I need is to extract the following lines from the query

```
WHERE t.column1 = @param1
```

And

```
AND t.column2 = @param2
```

The SQL code is defined inside IBM Cognos reports.

Any suggestion?

Comment: did you use %value% ?

Comment: You need to find a SQL parser and parse the string. If the query is as clean as you show, and `WHERE` is the last statement you can use a regular expression and capture anything after `WHERE`. Why do you want this though?

Comment: if you have string you can try `where t.column1 like '%value%'`, if it's a variable you can try `charindex(t.column1, @param1) > 0`

Comment: Yes, please explain for what task do you need to extract these lines.

Comment: You are not passing down user-defined sql, do you?

Comment: I'm working on a RPA project. Once that I extracted the line/s, I have to write them on a Excel file.

Comment: @Fildor the sql is defined on IBM Cognos reports.

Comment: ^^ That would have been a good point to add to the question. ;D You can [edit] it to append that piece of information, though.

Answer (score 0):

Please check this program

```
public static void Main()
    {
        string query = @"SELECT *
                        FROM table t
                        WHERE t.column1 = @param1
                        AND t.column2 = @param2";

        string[] queries = query.Split("\n");
        bool isConditionStarted = false;
        foreach (string q in queries)
        {
            if (isConditionStarted)
                Console.WriteLine(q.Trim());
            else if (q.Trim().ToLower().Contains("where"))
            {
                isConditionStarted = true;
                Console.WriteLine(q.Trim());
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: my fault, I didn't specified that I need to look for ""@paramx" word, not "where". the query has no new line inside of it, is all on the same line. thanks anyway!

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, including an explanation really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @PalleDue, Ok, i will make sure about the explaination

Comment: @AlexandruBucur, you mean that you want to get only the param conditions, Can you give me more output sample